# Shopware6.5 App How to change CMS Editor Preview of new CMS Element

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

I'm following the app guide to create custom CMS elements, the sidebar preview works but not the preview inside the CMS editor window, what am I missing?

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/content/cms/add-custom-cms-blocks.html

The DOM structure of the block in the CMS editor will look like this:

```
<div class="sw-cms-block-swag-image-text-reversed-component">
    <div class="sw-cms-slot sw-cms-slot-left"></div>
    <div class="sw-cms-slot sw-cms-slot-right"></div>
</div>
```

Where should I add this code?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]